# Compilation errors for custom AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, loader

I'm trying to compile the example at :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

In the onCreateLoader method:

```
@Override public Loader<List<AppEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
        return new AppListLoader(getActivity());
    }
```

I keep getting the following compilation error:

```
required: android.support.v4.content.Loader<java.util.List<com.example.AppEntry>>
 return new AppListLoader(getActivity());
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.. forget it. The AsyncTaskLoader I was using had wrong imports. Changed it to import from the support library and started working !